# executing a .jar file in a separate window

Tags: java, windows, cmd, jar, execute

How to execute my .jar file in a separate window? My .jar file now only executes within CMD on windows. I need to send this to a recruiter for a Java Traineeship and he asked me for a .jar file. But I assume he just want to double click it to execute it. Double click does not work. It does not open in a separate window but only within CMD.

**Manifest**

```
Main-Class: BattleShip
```

**Java code**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleShip {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] board = new int[7][7];
    int[][] ships = new int[5][2];
    int[] shoot = new int[2];
    int attempts=0,
        shotHit=0;

    //method initBoard is triggered to create the board with the number '-1' in all positions
    initBoard(board);
    //method initShips is triggered to fill the position of the 5 ships (row and column)
    initShips(ships);

    System.out.println();

    //the game begins using a do...while loop, game goes on until the player hits the 5 ships
    do{
        showBoard(board);
        shoot(shoot);
        attempts++;

        if(hit(shoot,ships)){
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);
            shotHit++;
        }                
        else
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);

        changeboard(shoot,ships,board);

    //condition of the loop is "shotHit!=5'
    }while(shotHit!=5);

    System.out.println("\n\n\nWell done soldier! You've destroyed 5 enemy ships in "+attempts+" attempts");
    showBoard(board);
}
//sets the value -1 in all blocks of the board
public static void initBoard(int[][] board){
    for(int row=0 ; row < 7 ; row++ )
        for(int column=0 ; column < 7 ; column++ )
            board[row][column]=-1;
}
//gets the int matrix and shows the board game
public static void showBoard(int[][] board){
    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5 \t6 \t7");
    System.out.println();

    for(int row=0 ; row < 7 ; row++ ){
        System.out.print((row+1)+"");
        for(int column=0 ; column < 7 ; column++ ){
            if(board[row][column]==-1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"~");
            }else if(board[row][column]==0){
                System.out.print("\t"+"*");
            }else if(board[row][column]==1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"X");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

//this method randomly select 5 pairs of integers numbers, which are the location of the 5 ships
public static void initShips(int[][] ships){
    Random random = new Random();

    for(int ship=0 ; ship < 5 ; ship++){
        ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(7);
        ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(7);

        //let's check if that shot was already tried 
        //if it was, just finish the do...while when a new pair was randomly selected
        for(int last=0 ; last < ship ; last++){
            if( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]) )
                do{
                    ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(7);
                    ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(7);
                }while( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]) );
        }

    }
}

//gets a shot (row and column) of the user, and stores in variable shot []
public static void shoot(int[] shoot){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Row: ");
    shoot[0] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[0]--;

    System.out.print("Column: ");
    shoot[1] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[1]--;

}

//checks if given shot hit a ship
public static boolean hit(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){

    for(int ship=0 ; ship<ships.length ; ship++){
        if( shoot[0]==ships[ship][0] && shoot[1]==ships[ship][1]){
            System.out.printf("What a SOLDIER! You hit an enemy ship located in (%d,%d) with a hellstorm missle\n",shoot[0]+1,shoot[1]+1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//give a hint of how many ships are in that row and that column where the shot was given
public static void hint(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int attempt){
    int row=0,
        column=0;

    for(int line=0 ; line < ships.length ; line++){
        if(ships[line][0]==shoot[0])
            row++;
        if(ships[line][1]==shoot[1])
            column++;
    }

    System.out.printf("\nHint %d: \nRow %d -> %d ships\n" +
                             "Column %d -> %d ships\n",attempt,shoot[0]+1,row,shoot[1]+1,column);
}

//after the shot is given, the board is changed, showing that the shot was give (if hit or missed)
public static void changeboard(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int[][] board){
    if(hit(shoot,ships))
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=1;
    else
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=0;
}
}
```

** I compiled it in CMD and I execute it within CMD with java -jar BattleShip.jar**

Update: 
I can open .jar files now but now my own .jar file. 
I created a .bat file and it opens in CMD automatically and not in Java. Is it because my code does not have a UI?

Comment: I guess [tag:cmd] is not suitable here (read the tag info!)...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will, im a recent user on stackoverflow still need to find my way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just install the jarfix.exe and double click any jar executable..

Comment: Thank you I am going to try that when I am home.

Comment: @Amirates This will not make the jar file executable on the recruiter's machine (unless he/she runs the jarfix program). I think you should assume that the recruiter knows how to execute a jar file.

Comment: Yes I think so because he programs C# in his spare time so I think he has the Java SDK installed as he is a Java traineeship recruiter.

Comment: I can open now other .jar files just not my file for my code

Comment: The bat file  you created..needs to be in the same folder as your jar file, else you need to specify the path to the jar, not just the jar name. hope this helps

Comment: the .bat file is in the same folder. The folder is called BattleShiptim and I have 3 files located in there. BattleShip.bat, BattleShip.jar, manifest.txt

Comment: I copied everything now to C:/ instead of desktop and tried to open it through CMD and it says could not find or load main class jar-. I think something is wrong with the manifest file but what?